# How do I know which Experimental WebKit Features (located in Safari iOS’ advanced settings) are supposed to be toggled on vs. toggled off?

Tags: ios, safari, settings

I notice that with every new iOS update, many of the Experimental WebKit Features either are no longer relevant, or newer EWF’s appear out of nowhere. Some of the features that were initially toggled ON by default randomly end up off and placed in a different position than before on the list. I’ve been searching all over, and I just can’t seem to find the correct guide for which features to leave on or cut off. My anxiety tells me a few of them could create problems just from being toggled off when it should’ve been on…and I’d have no idea.

Does anyone have an updated 2022 version with all of the WK features and explanations and discriptions for each? I’d greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't worry about the list. Unless you are a web developer working with those upcoming features, or rely on some non-common web application that requires that specific experimental feature, there's no need to toggle any of the features on or off. Apple will do that automatically for you with their software updates, so that experimental features that are no longer experimental automatically becomes turned on permanently, and those features that are rejected will essentially be turned off permanently.

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer

Four recommendations:

1. The [actual](https://github.com/WebKit/WebKit) [WebKit source code](https://webkit.org/getting-the-code/) is probably the most authoritative and up-to-date reference for the usage and function of these “Experimental WebKit Features”, but also the *least* user-friendly.

   The most recent list of names, short descriptions, and defaults can be found here:

   > https://github.com/WebKit/WebKit/blob/main/Source/WTF/Scripts/Preferences/WebPreferencesExperimental.yaml

   *(Keep in mind that the current contents of the [`main`](https://github.com/WebKit/WebKit/tree/main/Source) branch are **almost guaranteed to be newer** that whatever version of WebKit/WebCore is installed on your device.)*

2. WebCore’s [features.json](https://github.com/WebKit/WebKit/blob/main/Source/WebCore/features.json) file has more information about *at least some* of the WebKit’s features, ‘experimental’ and standard alike.

   The entries in that file often indicate if the feature is ‘coming’ or ‘going’, and in many cases link to the relevant standard document or web site.

3. The WebKit wiki has a *(potentially infrequently-updated?)* list of feature information, and another page explaining the semantic difference between the ‘experimental’ and ‘internal’ categories:_

   - [Feature Flags](https://trac.webkit.org/wiki/FeatureFlags)

   - [Experimental and Internal Feature Flags](https://trac.webkit.org/wiki/ExperimentalAndInternalFeatureFlags)
4. **There are two sortable / filterable feature lists on the official WebKit site**:

   - [WebKit Feature Status](https://webkit.org/status/) *( [development-only](https://webkit.org/status/#?status=in%20development) | [under construction-only](https://webkit.org/status/#?status=under%20consideration) | [deprecated](https://webkit.org/status/#?status=deprecated) )*
   - [WebKit CSS Feature Status](https://webkit.org/css-status/) *( [experimental-only](https://webkit.org/css-status/#?status=experimental) | [obsolete-only](https://webkit.org/css-status/#?status=obsolete) )*

*(Note: the actual iOS menu referred to in the original question may only exist in the closed-source ‘Mobile Safari’ xcode wrapper used to build that app, from WebKit, at Apple.)*

---

### Next steps

Once you find an item of interest in that list, you can search that [same GitHub code repository](https://github.com/WebKit/WebKit) GitHub code repository to try to further understand what a particular setting might do.

Example:

```yaml
AccentColorEnabled:
  type: bool
  humanReadableName: "CSS Accent Color"
  humanReadableDescription: "Enable accent-color CSS property"
  defaultValue:
    WebKitLegacy:
      "PLATFORM(COCOA)" : true
      default: false
    WebKit:
      "PLATFORM(COCOA) || PLATFORM(GTK) || PLATFORM(WPE)": true
      default: false
    WebCore:
      "PLATFORM(COCOA) || PLATFORM(GTK) || PLATFORM(WPE)": true
      default: false
```

*(i.e. for more potential information about the specific “CSS Accent Color” ‘experimental setting’, search for `AccentColorEnabled` to see where else that term is used)*

---

#### Optional homework

*(edit: it appears they many have already done something just like this, producing the tables listed at #4 above)*

If anyone is bored, it should be trivial to write a script to auto-convert [that YAML file](https://github.com/WebKit/WebKit/blob/main/Source/WTF/Scripts/Preferences/WebPreferencesExperimental.yaml) into a table, web page, or ‘.csv’ file summarizing the contents.

- More human-readable documentation could then be updated on-demand.

  - e.g.: The rows and columns could then be filtered, sorted, etc. in familiar ways.

Even easier, that file may even *(partially?)* auto-import into a database, Google Sheets, or MS Excel with no modification *(or perhaps after a simple conversion to a `.json` file using a free web tool)*.